# How to get data from node.js to static javascript file in public folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am newbie in node.js. I have to send data from node to static javascript file. I have made a collection of questions which I want to sent to this javascript file :

```
var model = {
    questionSummary:[],
    noOfQuestions:0,
    init: function () {
        // if (!localStorage.getItem("questions")) {
        //     localStorage.setItem("questions", JSON.stringify([]));
        // }
        if(!localStorage.getItem("noOfQuestions")){
            localStorage.setItem("noOfQuestions",JSON.stringify(0));
        }
        else{   
         model.noOfQuestions = localStorage.getItem("noOfQuestions");
        }

        if (!localStorage.getItem("author")) { //todo
            localStorage.setItem("author","Anonymus");
        }
        if (!localStorage.getItem("currentQuestionId")) {
            localStorage.setItem("currentQuestionId", '1');
        }
        for(var index=1;index<=this.noOfQuestions;index++)
            this.questionSummary.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("question"+index)));
    },
    getAllQuestions: function () { //todo
        return this.questionSummary;
    },
    increment: function(questionBlockId) {
        this.questionSummary[questionBlockId].views++;
    },
    setter: function(property,value){
        localStorage.setItem(property, JSON.stringify(value));
    }
};
```

Instead of localStorage, I want to use that data in my code. I have used mongoose as the database storage and express as node framework.

I haven't made any route for this purpose, so any solution(advice) from scratch will be appreciated.

Comment: I am uncertain as to what exactly you need to know, but let me try:

You want to get data from your node.js server into the code you are running in a browser? In that case you need to use for example a route to serve the data from the server, and a ajax call to fetch it.

If you mean to inject the data into the file, you are talking about reading/writing the file to modify it.

Comment: @Stian I want to get data from node.js server into the code I am running into the browser so that I can render that data. Although I can get that data in the html but I need that data in my javascript file. I don't know much about Ajax, if you could provide a reference to that then it will be a great help.

Comment: exactly what you want to do be clear your question seems to be ambigous . Can't understand

Comment: Are you using any framework on your client-side? Most frameworks have easy abstractions to do this for you. 

If not, here is a reference to the native js method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

But if you are unfamiliar, I would look at frameworks like jQuery, Angular, etc.